# Update UISteppers value from textfield

Tags: textfield, uistepper

here is the case.

I would like to type a value in a text field and pass it to the current uisteppers value.

if for example current value is 2 and i enter 35 in the textfield then when i press the + button on the stepper the value should go to 36 (or by pressing - to 34)

Thanks

--------------------------------------EDIT AFTER 1st REPLY----------------------------------

thanks for fast reply, since i am fresher to all this i declared

`@interface GenericViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {`... in my header. and changed my code inside Generic Controller to:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    [textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
     NSLog(@"######PASS  DELEGATE ###############");
    return YES;
}

- (void) textFieldDidChange:(id)sender {

       UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)sender;
    textField = changeNfpHand;
    NSLog(@"##############################");
    NSLog(@"textfield is now  @------> : %f" ,  DateStepper.stepValue);
   self.DateStepper.stepValue = [textField.text doubleValue];

  //  self.DateStepper.stepValue = [self.Nfp.text doubleValue];
        NSLog(@"VALUE STEP is @------> : %f" ,  DateStepper.stepValue);
    NSLog(@"self.Nfp.text @------> : %@" ,  self.Nfp.text);
```

Now I am new to all this.. i tried to call  `[self textFieldDidChange:self];`  but no luck. it seems that i cant get it work...any ideas of what am i doing wrong ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the delegate of UITextField, add the following code, which will make the UIStepper's step  value be changing according to what you enter in UITextField.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    [textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
    return YES;
}
- (void) textFieldDidChange:(id)sender {
    UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)sender;
    self.stepper.stepValue = [textField.text doubleValue];
}
```